# Contact form 7 - No envia los emails desde hace unos dias

Tags: wordpress, email, contact-form-7

Tengo un WordPress con Contact Form 7. Funcionaban bien los formularios pero han dejado de funcionar, no he instalado plugins nuevos y no me sale error en la consola de las herramientas de Chrome. ¿Alguna idea de cómo averiguar qué pasa?

El formulario hace *submit* y también dice que `on_sent_ok: "alert('sent ok');"`
pero no llegan los emails. ¿Por qué puede ser?

Comment: Tenes actualizado a la ultima version Contact Form 7?
Esto afecta en varios casos el uso de este plugin. Si entras al formulario, te detalla algún error?

Answer (score 0):

Esto ocurre con frecuencia.

Si al actualizar el plugin y/o el Wordpress no se soluciona puede que el problema sea alguna de estas dos cosas:

1. **El dominio desde donde se envia el correo no es igual al dominio del sitio.** Esto es el "from" en Contact form 7. El campo de "from" o el correo que aparecerá como el que envia los mensajes debe tener el mismo dominio que el sitio web. Entonces si el sitio es *www.misitio.com* el correo que envia debe ser *ejemplo@**misitio.com*** (no puede ser gmail, ni hotmail, ni ningun otro).
   Esto es porque algunos hosting impiden el envio de correo desde dominios distintos a los del propio sitio para prevenir el envio de Spam.

*Generalmente si el campo "from" tiene puesto correctamente un correo con el dominio del mismo sitio pero aun asi no envia entonces es por la siguiente causa y se debe hacer lo siguiente.*

2. **El hosting deshabilitó la función mail() para prevenir el envio de Spam.** Entonces se deben enviar los correos por medio de SMTP. Para eso se debe instalar el plugin **WP Mail SMTP** y configurarlo con alguna cuenta de correo real.

El link del plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/

Aqui indican como configurarlo: https://www.gestudio.com/es/blog/view/instalacion_y_configuracion_smtp_en_wordpress